# Unable to get response of http request to a live website URL using node http module

Tags: node.js, http, protractor

Basically I want to test 500+ live website URLs and get the statusCode of them using protractor and getting help from node's http module.
But I'm not getting anything in response and all console statements related to the http request are ignored in my terminal.

I've tried using some external libraries such as axios and protractor-http-client but all are giving me same result.
I'm using TypeScript.

```
import request from 'request' // tried this one earlier instead of http
import https from 'https';
async testFunction () {
   const req = await https.get('https://www.google.com');
        let body = '';
        req.on('data',(d) => {
            body += d;
        });
        req.on('end',(resp) => {
            console.log(resp.statusCode); // Not printing in terminal at all
            body = JSON.parse(body);
        });
        req.on('response', (resp) => { // also tried information instead of response
           console.log(resp.statusCode); // Not printing in terminal at all
        });
        console.log(body); // printing as empty
    }
}
```

I would expect the response status code be 200.
I'm new to both protractor and node. So any kind of help and suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I have fixed it. I used mocha done() function. So my code is executing until I call the done() method. And I get the response before it ends the assertion.

Answer (score 1):

```
const http = require('http');
const res = http.request({        
    host: 'google.de', 
    method: 'get',
    path: '/'
}, (response) => {
    let dataStr = [];
    const receiveData = chunk => {
       const b = Buffer.from(chunk);
       dataStr.push(b);
    };
    response.on('end', () => {
        console.log('status Code:', response.statusCode);
        console.log('response:', Buffer.concat(dataStr).toString());
    });
    response.on('error', (e) => console.error(e));
    response.on('data', receiveData);
});
res.end();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but these console statements are not printing anything in terminal. The listeners you defined are not even being called on my side.
P.S I'm using protractor.

Comment: This should works in a node.js application, if u are in a Browser instance you can not do that. The Browser will not allow cross origin http requests. It must be setted by the User for allowing that.